# Intellisense issue with nested values in Web Essentials 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, intellisense, web-essentials

I can't imagine this issue happens for everyone because it renders Web Essentials completely unusable, so I'm really confused as to what's going on.

Here's what I would like to accomplish: a simple "a" tag block nested within another block (in this case, "body")

[image]

HOWEVER! The second I type "a", an intellisense dropdown pops up with suggestions.

[image]

I do not do anything to invoke this dropdown aside from typing "a". Once I then press space or open curly bracket, "align-content" is populated from the dropdown.

[image]

This is obviously worse than frustrating since it makes using the editor completely impractical. Similar things happen with other tags, too. "span" becomes "ruby-span" for instance.

I've checked the Web Essential settings and there's nothing there to deal with this. Can anyone replicate and help with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `esc` works when you do not want to utilize the intellisense options. I would think this is the best alternative given the intended purpose of intellisense.

Comment: That's not really a viable solution. I shouldn't have to hit `esc` every time I type a tag name.

Comment: Have you tried changing any of the intellisense options under `Tools> Options> Web Essentials > CSS`?

Comment: Yes, I toggled all of those on and off. No dice.

Comment: @Paul Did you ever figure this out? I'm still experiencing the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 with Web Essentials 2015.3 installed. I also have Web Workbench 3.4 installed, but I disabled the intellisense for that extension.

Comment: @Jeff sadly, no. I've just switched to using Sublime Text for all my code editing.

Comment: It appears this is directly related to Options>Text Editor>CSS>General>Auto List Members. When I uncheck that, it no longer suggests "align-content" when I try to enter in a nested anchor tag selector. The problem is that it no longer suggests anything ever for SCSS files. Turning off Options>Text Editor>SCSS>General>Auto List Members doesn't seem to make any difference. What would be great is if there was an extension that added html elements to the SCSS intellisense list. That way at least "a" would be the default.

Comment: The problem also still exists in VS2015, even without Web Essentials or Web Workbench installed.